# Raising to a square with TensorFlow with a Dataset class

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I want to write a neural network which look for a x^2 distribution without a predefined model. Precisely, it is given some points in [-1,1] with their squares to train, and then it would have to reproduce and predict similar for e.g. [-10,10]. 
I've more or less done it - without datasets. But then I tried to modify it in order to use datasets and learn how to use it. Now, I succeded in making the program run, but the output is worse then before, mainly it's constant 0.

Previous version was like x^2 in [-1,1] with linear prolongation, which was better.. [Previous output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E50e.png)
with a blue line being flat now. And the goal would be to coincide with a red one..

Here, comments are in Polish, sorry for that.

```
# square2.py - drugie podejscie do trenowania sieci za pomocą Tensorflow
# cel: nauczyć sieć rozpoznawać rozkład x**2
# analiza skryptu z:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140591/neural-network-to-predict-nth-square

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import reset_default_graph

# def. danych do trenowania sieci
# x_train = (np.random.rand(10**3)*4-2).reshape(-1,1)
# y_train = x_train**2
square2_dane = np.load("square2_dane.npz")
x_train = square2_dane['x_tren'].reshape(-1,1)
y_train = square2_dane['y_tren'].reshape(-1,1) 

# zoptymalizować dzielenie danych
# x_train = square2_dane['x_tren'].reshape(-1,1)
# ds_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
# batch_x = ds_x.batch(rozm_paczki)
# iterator = ds_x.make_one_shot_iterator()

# określenie parametrów sieci
wymiary = [50,50,50,1]
epoki = 500
rozm_paczki = 200

reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1])

weights = []
biases = []
n_inputs = 1

# inicjalizacja zmiennych
for i,n_outputs in enumerate(wymiary):
    with tf.variable_scope("layer_{}".format(i)):
        w = tf.get_variable(name="W", shape=[n_inputs,n_outputs],initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.02,seed=42))
        b=tf.get_variable(name="b",shape=[n_outputs],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
        weights.append(w)
        biases.append(b)
        n_inputs=n_outputs

def forward_pass(X,weights,biases):
    h=X
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        h=tf.add(tf.matmul(h,weights[i]),biases[i])
        h=tf.nn.relu(h)
    return h    

output_layer = forward_pass(X,weights,biases)
f_strat = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(output_layer,Y),1)
f_strat = tf.reduce_sum(f_strat)
# alternatywna funkcja straty
#f_strat2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(Y-y_train)/y_train)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003).minimize(f_strat)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # trenowanie
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train))
    dataset = dataset.batch(rozm_paczki)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epoki)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    ds_x, ds_y = iterator.get_next()
    sess.run(optimizer, {X: sess.run(ds_x), Y: sess.run(ds_y)})
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save = saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print("Model zapisano jako: %s" % save)

    # puszczenie sieci na danych
    x_test = np.linspace(-1,1,600)
    network_outputs = sess.run(output_layer,feed_dict = {X :x_test.reshape(-1,1)})

plt.plot(x_test,x_test**2,color='r',label='y=x^2')
plt.plot(x_test,network_outputs,color='b',label='sieć NN')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.show()
```

I think that the problem is with input of training data 
`sess.run(optimizer, {X: sess.run(ds_x), Y: sess.run(ds_y)})`
or with the definition of ds_x, ds_y. It's my first such a program..
So this was the output for the lines (insead of the 'sees' block)

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # trenowanie
    for i in range(epoki):
        idx = np.arange(len(x_train))
        np.random.shuffle(idx)
        for j in range(len(x_train)//rozm_paczki):
            cur_idx = idx[rozm_paczki*j:(rozm_paczki+1)*j]
            sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict = {X:x_train[cur_idx],Y:y_train[cur_idx]})
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save = saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print("Model zapisano jako: %s" % save)
```

Thanks!

P.S.: I was highly inspired by [Neural Network to predict nth square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140591/neural-network-to-predict-nth-square?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that conspire to give your model poor accuracy, and both involve this line:

```
sess.run(optimizer, {X: sess.run(ds_x), Y: sess.run(ds_y)})
```

1. Only one training step will execute because this code is not in a loop. Your original code ran `len(x_train)//rozm_paczki` steps, which ought to make more progress.
2. The two calls to `sess.run(ds_x)` and `sess.run(ds_y)` run in separate steps, which means they will contain values from *different batches* that are unrelated. Each call to `sess.run(ds_x)` or `sess.run(ds_y)` moves the `Iterator` on to the next batch, and discards any parts of the input element that you did not explicitly request in the `sess.run()` call. Essentially, you will get `X` from batch *i* and `Y` from batch *i+1* (or vice versa), and the model will train on invalid data. If you want to get values from the same batch, you need to do it in a single `sess.run([ds_x, ds_y])` call.

There are two further concerns that might impact efficiency:

3. The `Dataset` is not shuffled. Your original code calls `np.random.shuffle()` at the beginning of each epoch. You should include a `dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(x_train))` before `dataset = dataset.repeat()`.
4. It is inefficient to fetch the values from the the `Iterator` back to Python (e.g. when you do `sess.run(ds_x)`) and feed them back into the training step. It is more efficient to pass the output of the `Iterator.get_next()` operation directly into the feed-forward step as inputs.

Putting this all together, here's a rewritten version of your program that addresses these four points, and achieves the correct results. (Unfortunately my Polish isn't good enough to preserve the comments, so I've translated to English.)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate training data.
x_train = np.random.rand(10**3, 1).astype(np.float32) * 4 - 2
y_train = x_train ** 2

# Define hyperparameters.
DIMENSIONS = [50,50,50,1]
NUM_EPOCHS = 500
BATCH_SIZE = 200

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(x_train))  # (Point 3.) Shuffle each epoch.
dataset = dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

# (Point 2.) Ensure that `X` and `Y` correspond to the same batch of data.
# (Point 4.) Pass the tensors returned from `iterator.get_next()`
# directly as the input of the network.
X, Y = iterator.get_next()

# Initialize variables.
weights = []
biases = []
n_inputs = 1
for i, n_outputs in enumerate(DIMENSIONS):
  with tf.variable_scope("layer_{}".format(i)):
    w = tf.get_variable(name="W", shape=[n_inputs, n_outputs],
                        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(
                            mean=0.0, stddev=0.02, seed=42))
    b = tf.get_variable(name="b", shape=[n_outputs],
                        initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
    weights.append(w)
    biases.append(b)
    n_inputs = n_outputs

def forward_pass(X,weights,biases):
  h = X
  for i in range(len(weights)):
    h=tf.add(tf.matmul(h, weights[i]), biases[i])
    h=tf.nn.relu(h)
  return h

output_layer = forward_pass(X, weights, biases)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.squared_difference(output_layer, Y), 1))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003).minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  # (Point 1.) Run the `optimizer` in a loop. Use try-while-except to iterate
  # until all elements in `dataset` have been consumed.
  try:
    while True:
      sess.run(optimizer)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    pass

  save = saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved to path: %s" % save)

  # Evaluate network.
  x_test = np.linspace(-1, 1, 600)
  network_outputs = sess.run(output_layer, feed_dict={X: x_test.reshape(-1, 1)})

plt.plot(x_test,x_test**2,color='r',label='y=x^2')
plt.plot(x_test,network_outputs,color='b',label='NN prediction')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.show()
```