# How to build a nonlinear network in TensorflowJS?

Tags: model, tensorflow.js

How can I build a model in TensorflowJS that takes one input and one label?

The following example demonstrates the scenario:

```
x=1, y=1;

x=2, y=4;

x=3, y=9;

x=4, y=16;
```

I only could get linear models to work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add as `activation` something different from `linear`. Full list of possible activation functions [here](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.dense)

```js
(async() => {
const model = tf.sequential();
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 8, inputShape: [1]}));
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4, activation: 'relu'}));
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'relu'}));
 // Note that the untrained model is random at this point.
 const x = tf.tensor([[1], [2], [3]])
 const y = tf.tensor([[1], [4], [9]])
 model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
 const h = await model.fit(x, y, {epochs: 100})
 
 const t = model.predict(x);
 t.print()
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
```

Comment: This neural network is predicting the function `f(x) = -3.333 * 4x`.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf my goal is not to give the perfect model for predicting x^2. It is not what the OP asked for. I just illustrated how to use the activation on a layer. Your answer is just a fine tuning by adding more layer and setting a learning rate. You're wrong with your `f` function since sometimes the predicted value can be a zero tensor depending on the initialization of the weight.

Comment: Your answer makes it seem like using an activation function other than "linear" makes a NN non-linear. I tried to point out that this is not the case. Maybe you can add parts of your comment to your answer to make it more clear?

Comment: It is the activation that makes the network non linear. The number of layers on the other will determine the accuracy of the network, so will be the choice of the learning rate.

Comment: My bad, of course you are right regarding non-linearity.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same question (["Neural Network to predict nth square"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43140591/5627599)) on the `tensorflow` tag with two good answers. I will try to adapt the code to Tensorflow.js and repeat the most important parts as short answer. Please read the answers over there to get the full picture.

**Short answer:** This task is not easy for a neural network and you need a complex neural network for this too work. In addition, you need an activation function like `ReLU` so that the range of the output is not limited to a specific range (like for `sigmoid` between -1 and 1).

In the following network I'm adapting the code from the [answer of Miriam Farber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174690/5627599) creating a neural network with three dense layers with 50 units and an output layer with one unit. All layers are using the ReLU activation function.

```js
(async () => {
  // 1000 random values between -10 and 10
  const xArray = (new Array(1000)).fill(0).map(() => [20 * (Math.random() - 0.5)]);
  const yArray = xArray.map(x => x[0] * x[0]);
  const x = tf.tensor(xArray);
  const y = tf.tensor(yArray);

  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 50, activation: 'relu', inputShape: [1] }));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 50, activation: 'relu' }));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 50, activation: 'relu' }));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'relu' }));

  model.compile({
      optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.01),
      loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
  });
  await model.fit(x, y, {
    epochs: 10,
    callbacks: {
        onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => console.log(`Epoch ${epoch}, loss: ${logs.loss}`),
    }
  });
  const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([[-5], [0], [5], [9], [20]]));
  console.log('Results for: -5, 0, 5, 9, 20');
  prediction.print();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.7/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

The code is able to predict the result in the range of `(-10; 10)` with reasonable accuracy (keep in mind, the network was trained for 10 epochs with 1000 values). However, the network fails to predict values outside of the trained data (like the `20` in the example).

Comment: I've ran your snippet and I see such an output: `Tensor [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]`. Strange? I can't figure out, what's going on: I'm getting a straight line on my own sample. Your example doesn't work for me as expected. By the way, I get zeroes for @edkeveked example too.